# Error promoting secondary DC (Windows Server 2012)

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, domain-controller

I am trying to promote second DC server. Primary and secondary servers are both Server 2012 R2.

I joined secondary server to domain, but when i try to promote it, I get the following error.

> Verification of outbound replication failed. Error reading the NTDS
>   settings on replication source domain controller SERVER1.domain.org.
>   The operation did not complete successfully because it would cause an
>   oplock to be broken. The caller has requested that existing oplocks
>   not be broken.

Any Idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

That sounds... awful.

I found this Technet article which concluded with the OP discovering RPC was being blocked by firewall: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/20ea278d-c3b5-435e-aec6-1fab0aa286dc/verification-of-outbound-replication-failed-error-reading-the-ntds-settings-on-replication-source?forum=winserverDS

Take a look at your network communication and **make sure you're not blocking critical traffic between the two machines. This is the most likely answer.**

Next, make sure there aren't any serious network misconfigurations such as incorrect subnet masks, DNS server configurations, etc.

Third, you'll need to do a deep dive into the health of your Active Directory installation. Use of the DCDIAG tool, REPADMIN, etc. There could be something very wrong with the AD installation.